# Why am I getting a "Type Error Dialog is not a Function" using jQuery UI?

Tags: jquery-ui, dialog

When I click of a Button I'm using the following code for a function for a Dialog:

```
function Confirmation(msg1){
if ($('#exportSales').length == 0) {
        $(document.body).append('<div id="exportSales">'+msg1+'</div>');
    } else {
        $('#exportSales').html(msg1);
    }

    $("#exportSales").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        show: "blind",
        hide: "explode",        
        height: 450,
        width: 1000,
        modal: true
    });

    $( "#exportSales" ).dialog("open");
}
```

However, when I inspect this in FireBug it is showing this error in the console:

```
TypeError: $(...).dialog is not a function [Break On This Error]

modal: true
```

**EDIT**: There is another dialog also in the document that runs fine. when I comment out that one then this dialog then starts working. 
How do I change my code so they can work together in the same page?

Comment: do you have included jquery-ui.js file

Comment: Ex: `<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>`

Comment: Jquery and Jquery UI are included, I have another dialog box which is opening but this one is not. Should i put this in document ready?

Comment: how is this method called

Comment: Called from 
<input type="button" id="btn_export_sales" onclick="javascript: Confirmation('Active File Export');">

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This Occurred Because of **two** `Jquery` Files Being Included. So Watch out for you source code. This may help you get out of this stupid error.

Comment: I have an angularjs app (using jquery) mixed with legacy javascript code on page that requires jquery to be included as a global scope variable by using script tag. That is when this crazy error showed up. My solution was to stop using jquery in the angularjs app, which turns out to be not that hard.

Comment: How do you know that jQuery was loaded twice?

Answer (score 1):

Also Check if Jquery Ui Script is loaded properly or not